# GlobalKey<FormState> has no validate() method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am defining the key for my form like so:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

I am passing it to my form like so:

```
Form(key: _formKey)
```

However, when I try to access `_formKey.validate()` I get the following error:

```
 lib/screens/checklists/AccidentChecklist.dart:341:54: Error: The method 'validate' isn't defined for the class 'GlobalKey<FormState>'.
 - 'GlobalKey' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'FormState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/form.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'validate'.
            _nextStepButton(_formKey.validate())
```

I really have no clue why I'm receiving this error because as we all know, this method exists, I'm quite experienced with Flutter and wouldn't be asking this question unless I was truly stumped, any suggestions?

Flutter version info:

> Flutter 1.24.0-4.0.pre.107 • channel master •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 35a94f70e1
> (5 months ago) • 2020-10-27 23:47:04 -0700 Engine • revision
> 64e6599910 Tools • Dart 2.11.0 (build 2.11.0-260.0.dev)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is

```
_formKey.currentState.validate();
```

not

```
_formKey.validate()
```

Comment: If the answer worked, dont forget to accept it using the tick mark next to it so that people who face this problem in the future know the right answer and I get some points too :)

Comment: I'm waiting. I can't accept it for another 8 mins, sorry! :)

Comment: No problemo. Do it when you can

Answer (score 1):

Add Null Check to the validate method

```
formKey.currentState!.validate()
```